# Code is skipping a command in the program. (C)

Tags: c, if-statement

Brief Description of Code: It's a quadratic equation calculator. It helps you find the roots of an equation.

Code:

`````````````````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
  int a, b, c, real;
  float root1, root2, img, dis;
  char solve;

  printf("Do you want to solve an equation (y/n): ");//Ask user if they want to solve an equation
  scanf("%c", &solve);

  if(solve == 'n'){//Terminate program
    return 0;
  }

  if(solve == 'y'){//Code for calculation
    printf("\nInput the number");
    printf("\n````````````````");
    printf("\nA: ");//Store number for a, b, c for the quadratic formula
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nB: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("\nC: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    dis = (b*b) - (4*a*c);//calculation for the discriminent

    //printf("%f", dis); Check the discriminant value

    if(dis > 0){//Calculation for the real root
      root1 = ((b*-1) + sqrt(dis))/(2*a);
      root2 = ((b*-1) - sqrt(dis))/(2*a);

      printf("\nRoot 1: %.2f", root1);
      printf("\nRoot 2: %.2f", root2);

      return 0;
    }

    if(dis = 0){//Calculation for no discriminent
      root1 = (b*-1)/(2*a);
      printf("\nRoot 1 and 2: %.2f", root1);
      return 0;
    }

    if(dis < 0){//Calculation for complex root
     dis = dis * -1;

     //printf("\n%f", dis);  !!!Testing to see why the code isn't functioning!!! It skipped this

     root1 = (b*-1)/(2*a);
     img = (sqrt(dis))/(2*a);

     printf("Root 1 and 2: %.2f ± %.2f", root1, img);

     return 0; 
    }
  }
}
`````````````````

Problem: It works perfectly fine if the discriminant is greater than zero. But when it's equal to or less than zero, it skips everything in the code for some reason. I'm having trouble finding the error. I put in printf statement to see what is the value of the discriminant and I kept a printf statement in the if statement to see if it will printf anything, but it skipped that.

Output I got:

`````````````````
gcc version 4.6.3
Do you want to solve an equation (y/n):  y

Input the number
````````````````
A:  1
B:  2
C:  5 //It ends here
`````````````````

Output I want:

`````````````````
gcc version 4.6.3
Do you want to solve an equation (y/n):  y

Input the number
````````````````
A:  1
B:  2
C:  5
Root 1 and 2: -1±2i
`````````````````

Comment: For starters, use `==` for comparison, not `=`!

Comment: `dis = 0` should be `dis == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at you `if` statement for `dis = 0`, it should:

```
if(dis == 0)
```

That should fix all your problems. Nice job with the code. Just a beginner mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the operator `=` when you want the operator `==`.

`a == b` checks if 2 numbers are equal, while `a = b` sets the first to the value of the second.

In other words, change `dis = 0` to `dis == 0`.

Comment: You should comment and flag as a typographical error instead of answering.